# Delete WordPress plugin Repository

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I wanted to create a WP plugin. So I requested and my request was approved by WordPress.org But I don't want to develop that plugin anymore. How can I delete the repository forever or request its deletion.

Comment: Good question. Curious about the answer too.

Comment: i had ask for this on the wp-hackers-list and all answers was insufficient :( 
Ia had also mail to wp.org and i had also no answer and solution
I had change the readme.txt to no support for the plugin and also delete all files in trunk, copy to tags in SVN, thats all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please mail `plugins@wordpress.org` and ask them to remove your plugin. Provide all infos and explain that you won't start to develop the plugin so the name should no longer be blocked.

I would use the same email as while registering the plugin (maybe even replying to it) and I think they will remove it after some days.

Comment: I did this and it actually worked.. But did take a few days... Thank you very much..

Comment: Does anyone know if this is still an active answer? We have emailed them repeatedly without reply. @hakre

Comment: Have you waited a few days each? Just asking, I can imagine that there is no fixed mode of operation so at some times of the year, you need to have more patience maybe. Normally emails don't get lost, so I do not see any need to *repeatedly* mail them.

Comment: @Otto Maybe you can help this soul?

Comment: Since April 2020 you can do it yourself from wordpress.org "Go to the ADVANCED VIEW link on sidebar of your plugin page and scroll down to the CLOSE THIS PLUGIN section."

Answer (score 6):

To remove a plugin from the WordPress repository, first delete the code via SVN. Then email [plugins@wordpress.org](http://mailto:plugins@wordpress.org) using the email you registered with at wordpress.org (for the account that is the author of the plugin).  They will delete it within a few days and email you back to confirm.  They basically hide the plugin pages. The plugin slug remains blocked and your project can be resurrected if you can convince them to re-open it.

You can also remove your themes from the WordPress Theme repository in a similar way by emailing [themes@wordpress.org](http://mailto:themes@wordpress.org) using the email you registered with at wordpress.org (for the account that is the author of the theme).

I did this myself this week to remove an old theme and plugin that I'd abandoned and that have since been superseded by other peoples work.

Comment: You don't need to delete the code via SVN first. Just email the plugins address and let us handle it. And there is no themes address, as such. However, you can email the theme-reviewers mailing list and they can handle it for you.

Comment: The themes@ address worked fine for me (they deleted the theme and replied to me with a confirmation).  Also the plugin deletion confirmation email told me specifically to ensure I deleted the code from SVN myself since they didn't do it.

Comment: Deleting the code from SVN is not necessary nor desirable. You'll find the email says that you can delete it if you like, nothing more. I happen to know because I wrote that form email. SVN maintains history, deleting from it only deletes it from the latest version, the historical record will always be available. Code cannot be "deleted" from it.

Comment: Only giving my experience and not looking to clash with you, but deleting the whole plugin SVN tree does mean the current package is empty.  Sure you can go back to an old revision but really bad code does not improve with age; it stays bad and so why keep it?  Plus the plugin name is taken forever in the repo - better to tidy stuff up IMO - namespaces are recyclable and more valuable than the bad / outdated / unwanted code they often contain.

Comment: Namespaces are not recyclable in our system. Too much confusion and clash with people running old code. Rule 1: we don't break people's sites if we can avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've heard, you can't really remove it from the repository.  Besides that, you really shouldn't.  Someone somewhere might still be using the code and might need the repository for reference.  Or it might be a good educational tool later on down the road.

But if you want to stop supporting it (i.e. **abandon** the plug-in), there is something you can do ...

Upload a new readme file to the repository explaining that you're no longer developing or supporting the plug-in.  Make the message large and the first thing people will see in the readme.  Also make sure you put a reference in the description of the plug-in's core PHP file explaining that there will be no future versions.

If, in the future, another developer wants to take over you can always assign them as the owner of the repository.  Otherwise, it will just sit there in the archives with its "This plug-in is no longer supported or being actively developed!" message to warn people away.

Comment: I haven't put up anything in the repository yet...

Comment: Then don't worry about it.  If there's nothing in the repository, there's nothing to support.  Though you might want to commit a readme file explaining that you have no intention to provide any updates.

Comment: You can delete it, look at the answer above...

Comment: I misunderstood your question to mean that you had already submitted a plugin to the repository, not that you were just holding the name open ... but it's nice to know that plugins *can* be removed ... though I don't think any that have already been added ever *should* be as per my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily delete files from **SVN REPOSITORY**:

1) Download and Install [Tortorize SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html)  
2) right click on desktop (or elsewhere) and click **SVN CHECKOUT** and enter plugin url (i.e. `http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/my-cmbe-plugin/`)

3) Enter the downloaded folder, right click inside empty area and click **`Tortorize SVN>REPO browser`**  and delete any files.

Answer (score 0):

As @Maciej said in his comment, this is now something you can do yourself from the "ADVANCED VIEW" in the sidebar of your plugin page, then scroll down to the CLOSE THIS PLUGIN section.

The action is permanent.